# How to display Highcharts x-axis time stamp labels inside tooltip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

In my chart I have these time stamp that are displayed on the x-axis
[image]

How do I make them display in the tooltip when I hover over to certain point in the chart?

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...
    xAxis: {
      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          let seconds = this.value * 5;
          let t = new Date(1900, 1, 1, 9, 30, 0);
          t.setSeconds(t.getSeconds() + this.value * 5);
          return `${t.getHours()}:${t.getMinutes()}:${t.getSeconds()}`
        }
      },
      tickInterval: 2
    },
 });
```

Can someone please help as I am not able to figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same approach in `pointFormatter` as in the labels formatter function.

```
            tooltip: {
                pointFormatter: function(){
                    let t = new Date(1900, 1, 1, 9, 30, 0);
                    t.setSeconds(t.getSeconds() + this.x * 5);
                    
                    return `
                        Time: ${t.getHours()}:${t.getMinutes()}:${t.getSeconds()}
                        Y: ${this.y} 
                        Value: ${this.value}
                    `
                }
            }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jf9x8y3q/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormatter

Answer (score 0):

The Highcharts API has a pointFormat property for tooltips, where you can specify the HTML (e.g. `<p>Tooltip data: {variable}</p>`). You can find the API reference here: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormat

Or you could use pointFormatter to specify a callback function instead (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormatter).